# chai expect unclear behavior

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a test case which is expected to fail.

```
expect.fail('Not Found');
```

Tes is failing as expected but the error message is incorrectly populating in local and on Heroku server

on local

```
{ AssertionError: expect.fail()
    at Object.<anonymous> ()
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (58)
  message: 'expect.fail()',
  showDiff: false,
  **actual: 'Not Found',**
  expected: undefined,
  operator: undefined }
```

on heroku

```
{ AssertionError: Not Found
  **message: 'Not Found',**
  showDiff: false,
  actual: undefined,
  expected: undefined,
  operator: undefined }
```

When I do assertion

expect(err.message).to.eql('Not Found');

Pass on local but fails on server ! any idea what might be wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `expect.fail(err.message, 'Not Found', 'It Throws a failure.')`

Comment: To me - it is throwing the error for "err" but I was able to solve by following documentation of chai expect - expect(actual, expected ,message)